# what file format should I use to save a gigantic list of strings in python?

Tags: python

I have a program that's about to go through 40,000 .ai files and use pytesseract to read each one and turn what it reads into a string.  The idea is that I'll save all of this strings in a giant list that I can go through later and do some regex work on.  Because there are so many files, I want the output file that contains the list to be as small as possible, but still be in a format I can easily deal with later.  From what I can tell json is the best format for this, but maybe txt or csv, but I'm not sure though.

Also, I'm worried about whether or not I need to be worried about memory. The way the program works is it iterates through each ai file, turns it into a string, and appends that string to a list that starts out empty, and then once the program is done iterating through the ai files it saves the list to a file.  I'm wondering if, before the moment when the final list is saved to a file, does that list live in the computer's memory, and would 40,000 ai files turned to strings be too much for the memory to handle?

Comment: This is why databases were invented.

Comment: It depends on how long these generated strings are, and what their format is. If the strings are large, its best to write as you go. But then you need to demark them somehow in your file. If the strings don't contain newlines, then adding a newline after each of them would work. You could even write a compressed file to reduce space on disk. You could even write each ai string as a separate file in the hopes of parallelizing the regex work you do later.

Comment: Select tags that tell us what your question is about. Please don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: As for your question -- We don't know how much (or little) text each of these files contain and how much memory you have on your computer. Since each character takes ~4 bytes of space, 40k files with 10k words each will take ~2GB of memory, which is not too much. If you have a list that contains text from all files, then _yes, of course that list will live in memory!_ If you want to avoid using so much memory, you can save each entry to a text or csv file as you process the ai file, but then you'll have to load everything (or a subset of everything) back into memory to process it anyway.

Comment: I don't know or use Adobe Illustrator but AFAIK, `.ai` files are vector files, so surely you don't want to OCR them as though they were bitmap files? I imagine you can find text in them with PDF tools, or Inkscape.

Comment: If you have 40,000 files, I imagine you'll want to use multiprocessing else you'll be there all year so I would think about saving the strings for each file in a separate, independent place so you can write many at once. How about saving strings from `file1.ai` in `file1.txt`?